# Data Augmentation in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

In config file, we are given the default Augmentation option as shown below.

```
data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
```

But I wondered how it works with the bounding box(ground truth box) values given with the training images. so I looked at [preprocessor.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py#L443), random_horizontal_flip() takes 'boxes=None' parameter. Since no argument is given in the config file, I assume this flip does not account bounding box when it does the random horizontal flip.

My question is what arguments do I use to add the value of bounding box in the config file in the code snippet section shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boxes will get flipped too. If you look down in the preprocessor file, you'll notice a map that defines what inputs of the tensor dictionary will get passed into the preprocessing function. The groundtruth boxes are passed into random_horizontal_flip.

Comment: are you referring to [this map function](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py#L2913) ? @derek