# Tensorflow Object Detection API Data Augmentation Bounding Boxes

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, bounding-box, data-augmentation

For Object Detection via the Tensorflow API using the model_main.py, when I use i.e. `random_horizontal_flip` in the `data_augmentation_options` in the `train_config` of my pipeline.config, are my bounding boxes also affected? This is very important, as otherwise these options are not applicable. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50293090/10673713) is the same question, but it was not properly answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the bounding boxes are affected in the same way.
Specifically for `random_horizontal_flip`, you can verify it by looking at the [function](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py#L443), which also receives boxes.
Flipping the bounding boxes is performed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py#L517).
Note not all augmentation options need bounding box altering, but those who do - alter the bounding box accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @netanel-sam. I could also find the corresponding function in the preprocessor.py, but I was not able to find the part where this information is passed into the function `random_horizontal_flip`. Do you know where exactly this happens?

Comment: It happens here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py#L3206. `func` is a preprocessing function (iterated over all `preprocess_options`), `args` is the arguments to the preprocessing function such as image, bounding boxes, masks, etc. `params` is parameters to a preprocessing function, e.g. scaling ratio, cropping parameters etc. In case of `random_horizontal_flip` there aren't interesting ones (keypoint permutation).

Comment: Okay, and where are these `preprocess_options` defined? I can't even find the place where the preprocessor.py is called at all. I have a really hard time navigating through all these connected scripts. I did a 'usage search' with my IDE and it couldn't find any usage of the preprocessor.py as well as the `preprocess` function. I could follow the path of the pipeline.config in the model_main.py and where it gets processed into the `train_and_eval_dict` and then via the `model_lib.create_train_and_eval_specs` into `train_spec` where I suppose the information for the data augmentation is.

Comment: But that's pretty much where it ends. `train_spec` is then fed into the `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate`but I cannot find anything about the preprocessing there.

Comment: It is indeed hard to navigate. You should delve in inputs.py. The function `augment_input_data` receives the tensor which contains the data (images, labels, etc), and the augmentation options, and then applies them in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/inputs.py#L290. This function is called by `transform_and_pad_input_data_fn` which reads the data augmentation options right from the train config file, and creates `data_augmentation_fn` which is then used as part of the all transformations to the input data.